# Can't build or package kotlin maven based spring boot project

Tags: spring, jpa, kotlin

I have a kotlin spring boot project, this project is my first example in kotlin that I have developed.
I use jpa and metamodel for building queries. when I try to build the project I encounter with "cannot find symbol" error message.
I attached the [here](https://gofile.io/?c=sUOU90) the source code.
can anyone build my source code and find my exact point of failure.
I also added Employee entity , Repository classes and pom file context.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tblEmployees")
open class Employee : Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "employeeId", unique = false, nullable = false)
    var employeeId: Long? = null ;

    @Column(name = "EmployeeGuid", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 20)
    var employeeGuid: String? = null

    @Column(name = "FirstName", unique = false, nullable = false, length = 20)
    var firstName: String? = null

    @Column(name = "LastName", unique = false, nullable = false, length = 20)
    var lastName: String? = null

    @Column(name = "Role", unique = false, nullable = false, length = 20)
    var role: String? = null

    @Column(name = "RegisterServerIP", unique = false, nullable = false, length = 20)
    var registerServerIP: String? = null

    @Column(name = "RegisterClientIP", unique = false, nullable = false, length = 20)
    var registerClientIP: String? = null

    @Column(name = "RegisterDate", nullable = false)
    var registerDate: Int? = null

    @Column(name = "RegisterTime", nullable = false, length = 8)
    var registerTime: String? = null

    @Column(name = "RegisterDateComplete", nullable = false, length = 50)
    var registerDateComplete: String? = null
}


@Repository
interface RepoEmployee : JpaRepository<Employee, Long>, RepoEmployeeExtension {

    fun findByFirstName(firstName: String): List<Employee> // default implementation
    fun findByLastName(lastName: String): List<Employee> // default implementation

    @Query("select e from Employee e where e.firstName like %:firstName%") // default implementation
    fun findContains(@Param("firstName") firstName: String): List<Employee>

}

@Repository
interface RepoEmployeeExtension {
    fun findInRange(from: Int, to: Int): List<Employee>
    fun findEmployeeByIdOnNQ(id: Long): Employee?
    fun searchEmployees(startIndex: Int, endIndex: Int ,employeeId: Long? , firstName: String? , lastName: String? , role: String? , registerDate : Int? , registerClientIP : String? ,
                        registerUserId: Long? , registerUserName: String? ): List<Employee>
}

class RepoEmployeeExtensionImpl : RepoEmployeeExtension {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var entityManager: EntityManager

    override fun findInRange(from: Int, to: Int): List<Employee> {
        val builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder()
        val query = builder.createQuery(Employee::class.java)
        val root = query.from(Employee::class.java)
        query.select(root)
        val q = entityManager.createQuery(query)
        q.firstResult = from
        q.maxResults = to
        return q.resultList
    }

    override fun findEmployeeByIdOnNQ(id: Long): Employee? {
        var employee = entityManager.createNamedQuery("NQfindEmployeeByCId").setParameter("id", id).resultList.stream().findFirst()
        return employee as? Employee; // nullable cast
    }
    override fun searchEmployees(startIndex: Int, endIndex: Int , employeeId: Long?, firstName: String?, lastName: String?, role: String?, registerDate: Int?, registerClientIP: String?,
                                 registerUserId: Long?, registerUserName: String?): List<Employee> {
        val criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder()
        val query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery<Employee>(Employee::class.java)
        val rootEmployee: Root<Employee> = query.from(Employee::class.java)

        //Convert LazyLoad to eager in  criteriaBuilder
//        val rootArUserJoin= rootEmployee.join(Employee_.current_registerUser , JoinType.INNER)
//        val rootArUserFetch= rootEmployee.fetch(Employee_.current_registerUser , JoinType.INNER)

        val criterias  = ArrayList<Predicate>()
        if (employeeId != null && employeeId != -1L) {
            criterias.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(rootEmployee.get(Employee_.employeeId), employeeId))
        }
        if (!firstName.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            criterias.add(criteriaBuilder.like(rootEmployee.get(Employee_.firstName), firstName))
        }
        if (!lastName.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            criterias.add(criteriaBuilder.like(rootEmployee.get(Employee_.lastName), lastName))
        }
        if (!role.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            criterias.add(criteriaBuilder.like(rootEmployee.get(Employee_.role), role))
        }
        if (registerDate != null && registerDate != -1) {
            criterias.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(rootEmployee.get(Employee_.registerDate), registerDate))
        }
        if (!registerClientIP.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            criterias.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(rootEmployee.get(Employee_.registerClientIP), registerClientIP))
        }
//        if (registerUserName != null && !registerUserName.isEmpty()) {
//            criterias.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(rootArUserJoin.get(ArUser_.userName), registerUserName));
//        }
//        if (registerUserId != null && registerUserId != -1L) {
//            criterias.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(rootArUserJoin.get(ArUser_.userId), registerUserId));
//        }

//        val rootArUserJoin= rootEmployee.join(Employee_.current_registerUser , JoinType.INNER)
//        val rootArUserFetch= rootEmployee.fetch(Employee_.current_registerUser , JoinType.INNER)
//
//        val criterias  = ArrayList<Predicate>()
//        if (employeeId != null && employeeId != -1L) {
//            criterias.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(rootEmployee.get(Employee_.employeeId), employeeId))
//        }
//        if (!firstName.isNullOrEmpty()) {
//            criterias.add(criteriaBuilder.like(rootEmployee.get(Employee_.firstName), firstName))
//        }
//        if (!lastName.isNullOrEmpty()) {
//            criterias.add(criteriaBuilder.like(rootEmployee.get(Employee_.lastName), lastName))
//        }
//        if (!role.isNullOrEmpty()) {
//            criterias.add(criteriaBuilder.like(rootEmployee.get(Employee_.role), role))
//        }
//        if (registerDate != null && registerDate != -1) {
//            criterias.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(rootEmployee.get(Employee_.registerDate), registerDate))
//        }
//        if (!registerClientIP.isNullOrEmpty()) {
//            criterias.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(rootEmployee.get(Employee_.registerClientIP), registerClientIP))
//        }
//        if (registerUserName != null && !registerUserName.isEmpty()) {
//            criterias.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(rootArUserJoin.get(ArUser_.userName), registerUserName));
//        }
//        if (registerUserId != null && registerUserId != -1L) {
//            criterias.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(rootArUserJoin.get(ArUser_.userId), registerUserId));
//        }

        query.select(rootEmployee).where(*criterias.toTypedArray())
        val q = entityManager.createQuery(query)
        q.firstResult = startIndex
        q.maxResults = endIndex
        val results = q.getResultList()
//        for (employee in results) {
//            println(employee.firstName + " - " + employee.lastName )
//        }
        return results

    }
}
```

```
            <plugins>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                    <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.8.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>schemas</id>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>schema</goal>
                                <goal>protocol</goal>
                                <goal>idl-protocol</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/avro-schemas</sourceDirectory>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin/</outputDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>xjc</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>xjc</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</outputDirectory>
                        <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>


                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <args>
                            <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                        </args>
                        <compilerPlugins>
                            <plugin>spring</plugin>
                            <plugin>jpa</plugin>
                            <plugin>all-open</plugin>
                        </compilerPlugins>
                        <pluginOptions>
                            <option>all-open:annotation=javax.persistence.Entity</option>
                            <option>all-open:annotation=javax.persistence.Embeddable</option>
                            <option>all-open:annotation=javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass</option>
                        </pluginOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
                            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>kapt</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>kapt</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <sourceDirs>
                                    <sourceDir>src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                                </sourceDirs>
                                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                                    <annotationProcessorPath>
                                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
                                        <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
                                    </annotationProcessorPath>
                                </annotationProcessorPaths>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>


                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <annotationProcessorPaths>
                            <path>
                                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                                <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                                <version>5.3.15.Final</version>
                            </path>
                        </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>process</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>process</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <processors>
                                    <processor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</processor>
                                </processors>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                            <version>5.3.15.Final</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>add-source</id>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>add-source</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <sources>
                                    <source>target/generated-sources/</source>
                                </sources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>build-info</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>build-info</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <additionalProperties>
                                    <build.number>${buildNumber}</build.number>
                                </additionalProperties>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>buildnumber</id>
                            <phase>validate</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>create</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <format>{0,number}</format>
                        <items>
                            <item>buildNumber</item>
                        </items>
                        <doCheck>false</doCheck>
                        <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
                        <revisionOnScmFailure>unknownbuild</revisionOnScmFailure>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
```

Comment: Hello, the good practice is to put your code examples in the question. It will make it easier to get answers to it because very few people will move to another place just to read your code...

Comment: you're right, but i think there's just something wrong in my project settings structure.

Comment: as you said , I added the related class codes to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Kotlin compiler plugin with the jpa-plugin to make Kotlin and JPA generated Metamodel work:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <version>1.2.30</version>
    <configuration>
        <compilerPlugins>
        <plugin>jpa</plugin>
        </compilerPlugins>
        <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.30</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <!--...-->
</plugin>
```

Please read more about JPA and Kotlin here: https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin-jpa

Comment: I have this plugin in pom, but it doesn't work very well. the meta mode classes have been generated in build time but the kotlin compiler can't find relevant symbols in the generated package.